# Who's the doctor?

Tags: cryptic-clues

> A writer trapped in electronics manufacturer.

What am I?

---

**Hint 1**

> The answer is a noun.

**Hint 2**

> The clue is a sound alike type one, I don't know what tag to use for this.

Comment: First attempt, go light on me :P

Comment: The title makes me think of Dr. Who here... But I've never seen that show :/

Comment: A proper crytic should have the number of letters.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore I don't really think that it is a cryptic :/ ...Maybe OP have no idea about cryptic clues

Comment: Dr. Sam Sung perhaps?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore "But I don't know how to stick the D in." Nice.

Comment: What the heck - someone should improve this tag, clicking it reveals nothing as to what type of puzzle this would be.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore I was tempted to say something too, but I never know what the audience here on SE is

Comment: @raystafarian  http://solving-cryptics.com/   I added it to the tag wiki, but someone will need to approve the edit.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore thanks. I'm glad I didn't attempt this puzzle ha. This would indicate the phrase "in by" instead of "in" or "by" is most likely significant?

Comment: Could someone tell me what "OP" stands for??

Comment: @Abhishek Original Poster. In this case, you are the OP.

Comment: @Abhishek This is what comes of using Hindi'ian English. I'd say remove that by. Anyway Chris, illiterate is a wrong word; imperfect would be better. I'd edit the 'by' myself, but I'm having a bad edit day.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer that I was looking for is

> ASUS

Explanation

> A "seuss" as in Dr Seuss who is a famous writer , the title refers to his pen name and the characters created by him the "Who's".

Comment: Mark it as accepted for others to see.

Comment: Keep in mind that we pronounce it as aay-soos, but others may have different pronunciations, like aay-sus or aa-soos.

Comment: @cst1992 will be more careful next time.

Comment: It's okay, no sweat :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NpYEJx7PkWE

Comment: @Daniel Couldnt have said it better!

Answer (score 11):

Is it:

> D J Krell

Which is

> **J. K. R**owling inside **Dell**

Comment: and what about the title?

Comment: A DJ is a musical therapist kind of doctor, maybe? Stuck on that part but the rest fits so well.

Comment: @manshu he's a *spin doctor*

Comment: @Paul Evans I don't know if dj krell is a writer, your answer fits, but it's not the one I had in mind

Comment: @Paul Evans besides the answer is a what not a who.

Comment: @Abhishek J. K. Rowling is a writer. And you said the answer was a noun. That could be a proper noun *i.e.* a person's name.

Comment: @Abhishek if it's a what not a who, then I'd say Doctor What.

Comment: @Daniel isn't he the father of Sherlock Holmes' friend?

Comment: Hmmmmm, something to think about.

Answer (score 4):

Answer could be:

> Dr. Dre

Because:

> He is a rapper and **writes** his own songs. His stage name contains "Dr." which stands for **doctor**. In 2008 he was one of co-founders of **Beats Electronics** that manufactures headphones.

Comment: (Note the cryptic-clues tag: this is a cryptic crossword style clue.)

Answer (score 3):

Proof of concept answer:

> Capaldi

because

> [One of these people with the surname Pal who is a writer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pal_(surname)) inside of the company name of [Cadi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadi_Scientific) (Scientific) produces Capaldi, last name of [Peter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Capaldi), known for playing The Doctor on Doctor Who

Comment: Someone made DW fit!!!

Answer (score 2):

Could it be:

> Linus Pauling

Because

> He is a doctor - a PhD in chemistry - also two Nobel prizes!! 
>  LG is an electronics manufacturer. 
>  In us Paulin. Tom Paulin is a poet https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Paulin

Comment: (Note the cryptic-clues tag: this is a cryptic crossword style clue.)

Comment: (Note the self proclaimed moderator.)

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be:

> Larking: this is a gerund, see [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/larking?s=t) for the definition. Although chiefly known for acting, Alan Arkin is the author of many books (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Arkin#Writing) for a partial list). LG is an electronics manufacturer. Put LG around Arkin and voila! ... Now I'm thinking a bit. Adam Arkin played a doctor in the series Chicago Hope, which would fit with the title but as far as I know, he didn't write anything. Possibly this is merely a coincidence.

Comment: Cryptic clues include their definitions - it's not just wordplay.

Comment: @Deusovi What do you mean "include their definitions"? Aside from the doctor thing not totally fitting, this seems pretty in line with cryptic-clued answers I've seen in the past.

Comment: @question_asker: I mean that there's no "frolicking or carefree adventure" in the clue - the wordplay is only half of the cryptic clue, and while the answer fits the wordplay nicely, it doesn't leave any of the clue for the definition.

Comment: @Deusovi I guess I'm going to need an example of what you mean, because, aside from going through an entire cryptic crossword to find counterexamples, I can't figure out what you mean by "definition" here. Not trying to be difficult, just not getting what you mean.

Comment: @question_asker: Cryptic clues have two parts: a definition half and a wordplay half. The definition half works like a "straight" crossword clue: if this is the answer, then where is the definition in "A writer trapped in by electronics manufacturer"?

Comment: @Deusovi No no, I know what cryptic clues are, but I struggle to see how meeting the definition of both parts of the clue is not meeting the definition. The answer to the very first example [here](http://solving-cryptics.com/) is not remotely defined by the clue, only by part of the clue.

Comment: @Deusovi This is all further confused by the fact that, in this case, there are more than two definitions to be met: writer, electronics manufacturer, and doctor (given by the title, not the clue itself); all of that is in addition to whatever definition you feel is not being met

Comment: @question_asker The problem is that the definition of the answer Hugh gave is *nowhere* in the clue. It's not that the answer is missing a definition from the clue, it's that the clue is missing a definition from the answer that would be there in a cryptic clue.

Comment: When egos collide, who will win... find out in the next comment... wait this is inspiring my next puzzle.

Comment: @Daedric Glad to see you're back!

Answer (score 0):

> [Dr. (Joseph) Bell](http://www.sherlockian-sherlock.com/dr-joseph-bell-the-real-sherlock-holmes.php)

With the following reasoning:

> A writer (RB) is the weakest part; there are [plenty of authors called RB Something](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=rb%20writer&oq=rb%20writer&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4j69i64.1397j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
>  ...inside an electronics manufacturer (DELL)
>  ...gives us a Dr. Bell; there are several such people, so I went with this chap.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Jacob M. Appel

Because

> Appel ~= Apple, which is an electronics manufacturer. And Dr. Appel is an author. No idea about the rest of the clues.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have any reputation to comment, so I'm making a separate answer, but this is entirely inspired by Paul Evans' existing answer:

> Dr Jekyll

Since this fits the doctor theme of the question, and (roughly) follows the same rules as the answer already given.

Comment: It's not a good thing to take anyone else's answer.

Comment: I wanted to comment but as I said, I can't do it. If this turns out right I would rather Paul's answer were accepted and this one deleted.

Comment: Even if you had dropped a comment, it would not be constructive in anyway

Comment: Constructive for (potentially) getting to the right answer? I merely meant that I could not have guessed this without reading Paul's answer. I don't understand what the correct course of action would be?